# Conversion Window to Page WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a program made. And I would like to publish on the web. My problem is that I have implemented in windows. I know for publishing Web pages needs to be done with Pages. Could I suggest that changes I make to pass as pages and then publish it? use WPF

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you basically have to switch from WPF to Silverlight. Silverlight is a lightweight subset of WPF, so something may work in a different way. You'll need to test it.

Second, in Silverlight you don't have the freedom of communicating with the filesystem as you had in WPF, because you are running in the restricted context of client's browser. Check that your operations still work; sometimes you'll need to use Silverlight-specific storage.

Lastly, for your application you'll indeed need to switch your top-level UI container from `Window` to `Page` (this perhaps is the easiest part). You'll have to *navigate* between pages instead of opening new windows, you maybe you'll need to revisit your visual design.